# update object value of all objects in javascript array with eslint error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, eslint

I have a javascript array like this:

```
const arr=[{name:"Test", sex:"Male"},{name:"Test2",sex:"Female"}, 
{name:"Test3",sex:"Male"}
 ]
```

I want to change name of all the objects in the arr to "common" like this:

```
const arr=[
{name:"common",
 sex:"Male"},
{name:"common",
 sex:"Female"},
{name:"common",
 sex:"Male"}]
```

What I am doing is:

```
arr.map((element) => {
      element.name= "common";
      return element;
    });
```

using `forEach`:

```
arr.forEach((element) => {
      element.name= "common";
      return element;
    });
```

This is working but giving a eslint warning stating:

```
no-param-reassign error
Assignment to property of function parameter 'element'.
```

How can I fix this without adding a skip for this? Maybe by using forEach or something else?Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `map` which produces a new array, use `forEach` which is more proper in this context.

Comment: forEach also throws the same eslint error

Comment: If you're getting the same error with `forEach` something's messed up with your env, try to restart/reinstall or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to change the incoming parameters in a function to prevent unintended behaviors.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign

You can change turn off this rule or you can reassign the parameter to another variable:

```
 arr = arr.map((element) => {
     let e = element;
     e.name = 'common';
     return e;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
const newArr = arr.map(element => ({ ...element, name: 'common' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const common = arr.map((item) => ({name: item.name = 'common', sex: 
item.sex}))
console.log(common)
```

This is object array mapping. The syntax requires you use element/item and then I used dot notation. Just replace the first item element with "common" and you're good to go!